# Who was "Sister Ninja"?

Tags: comics, dc, robin

In early issues of Robin (the Tim Drake ongoing) there was this character:

[image: SisterNinja]

Who was it? What was the storyline here?

Screen grab taken from the "Benedictions" storyline from Showcase '95 #5-6, Robin #6.

**Edit** As noted by Ishamael in the comments, the nun also appeared in Detective Comics #661 (also by Chuck Dixon)  where she performs a similar trick.

> **Robin:** Sister, do you think -
>
> (turns to look at the bench upon which she is sat, she is no longer
>   there)
>
> **Robin:** Wow. She could give Batman some lessons in dramatic exits.

Comment: The character also appears in Detective Comics #661 as part (6) of the KnightFall arc, which is where the "again" comes from.

Comment: @Ishamael you should expand that into an answer.

Comment: Not really, I don't know who the character is or what becomes of her, just that she's been in scenes before.

Comment: I have this vague memory of her ostensibly being revealed to be the mother to one of the characters in Bat-verse, but that might just be whispered rumors in the night.

Answer (score 1):

**The blind nun, Robin jokingly refers to as "Sister Ninja" lives at the aging remnants of St. Evangelina's Home For Boys which is maintained by several of the nuns as best they are able, since there have not been any children at the juvenile center for many years.**

I have included the information about the story arc which moved through a series of comics including:

- **Showcase '94 #5:** (May 1994) "*Benedictions Part 1*: My Midnight Confession"
- **Robin Vol. 2 #6:** (May 1994) "*Benedictions Part 2*: Deathangel"
- **Showcase '94 #6:** (early June 1994) "*Benedictions Part 3*: Vengeance and Forgiveness"

> Tim Drake is looking up old facts on Garfield Lynns, but finds that the man has been locked up in Arkham Asylum for so long there is hardly anything available about him, except his police file. Working feverishly on the computer, Tim traces Lynns' arrest record back to his youth in a juvenile detention center for multiple counts of arson, reckless endangerment, and even attempted homicide. His only listed place of residence is St. Evangelina's Home For Boys, an orphanage. Tim thus decides to visit the orphanage to see if anyone there remembers Garfield Lynns. After sneaking out of the house past his father, Jack Drake, Tim sets off as Robin.
>
> Finally, he comes to St. Evangelina's, now seemingly closed down, as judged by the somewhat grimy and dilapidated state, having fallen into disrepair. However, there are still some lights, so Robin slips in through a broken window to investigate. He finds himself in a peaceful, moss covered courtyard, where he is greeted by a blind nun, seated on a nearby park bench. The Boy Wonder apologizes for bothering her, but she brushes it off, simply stating that she is not used to sharing the courtyard with anyone. She notes the youth in Robin's voice, and tells him that there haven't been any young people in the orphanage for twenty years, but she and a few of the other old nuns continue to maintain parts of it. Robin questions the nun about Garfield Lynns, and she does recall faint memories of the troubled boy, but even more about his younger sister, Amanda Lynns.

Comment: The Detective #661 appearance is mentioned in the question.